# jQuery Toggle Multiple Divs Some Nested

Tags: jquery, html

Okay, let's try this from a different angle, I don't know that I'm being clear enough.

I have several nested divs. Inside those divs are two specific divs (col50) where the first has a further nested div (info). On the second col50 I have just links for viewing more information, editing information, and deleting information.

What I need is to click the 'more' link to slide down information from the nested div in the first col50. Both col50's are floated left, so they sit side-by-side. I've tried several forms of sibling, parent, this, etcetera and still haven't come up with a solution (as well as trying several solutions from other sites and this site).

It's just a simple toggle function and I can't figure out how to... what, climb the dom to reach the containing parent/child/sibling... maybe... to make it toggle.

Help?

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/f2SYT/

And below the updated code for html and jquery:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-100 clientContainer">
    <div class="col50">
        <p>Arnold Greenburg</p>
            <span class="info toggle">
        <p>This is more information.</p>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col50">
        <p> <a href="##" class="moreInfo">more</a>
            |
            <a href="##">edit</a> 
            |
        <a href="##">delete</a>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-100 clientContainer">
    <div class="col50">
        <p>Arnold Greenburg</p> <span class="info toggle">

                        <p>This is more information.</p>

                    </span>

    </div>
    <div class="col50">
        <p> <a href="##" class="moreInfo">more</a> |    <a href="##">edit</a> | <a href="##">delete</a>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.moreInfo').click(function () {
        $(this).parent('.clientContainer').child('.col50').find('.info').slideToggle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found **a** solution. It's a bit convoluted, but it is functional and works great.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$(".col50 + .col50 > p > a:first-of-type").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".info").slideToggle();
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
var $toggled = $(this).attr('href');
```

1st: it will be not jquery object, so make name toggled but not $toggled, to avoid misdirections.

2nd: it will set $toggled with value string "##"

3rd: calling $($toggled) is attempt to find all elements with ID "#", you dont have elements like this here.

If you want to find all links with href="##" use selector like this:

```
$("a[href=##]")
```

Check this jsfiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nf88K/)

Comment: What happens when I use your edited version is there's a slight shift in the link placement (up and down), but nothing more.

Comment: I've not changed your code, just showed you how to deal with divs. It's up to you to make whatever you want there.

Comment: I noticed you hadn't changed it, save for the edits.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding using the data attributes, something like `data-selector="info"`

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gvtRT/1/)

In the example I am not checking if anything is visible or not, I let the jQuery determine what action to take for me, there are drawbacks to this. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the use of targets and incrementing divs, as they'll be added dynamically later. I don't know that it makes a difference, but my content div and my link divs are floated next to one another with the same class names.